# How to run and close a roslaunch using button in Qt 5 (C++)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, ros

I want to build a UI with several buttons to launch a ros file and close the launch file. I'm stuck with the QProcess with others said.
I have followed several discussion:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/324076/kill-nodes-started-with-launch-file-properly-in-qt-how/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/360808/qt-creator-ui-to-run-roslaunch-by-clicking-a-button/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/209090/how-to-launch-a-roslaunch-in-qt-with-a-terminal-gui/

none of them succeed.
here is the latest code I tried (the result is nothing run when I push the button).

```
QString program = "roslaunch jackal_gazebo jackal_world.launch";
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
env.insert("launch","/opt/ros/melodic/share/jackal_gazebo");
myProcess->setProcessEnvironment(env);
myProcess->start(program);
myProcess->waitForStarted(-1);
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the suggested solution to send `SIGINT` signal to your process?

Comment: It just simply won't work.
I tried to call the roslaunch in the first time with below code, and nothing happened.

Comment: When I click the button, the UI suddenly exit

Answer (score 0):

If you can successfully start your nodes with the button then one way of closing them with button press would be to send a message to those nodes on a special topic for example: "/system/shutdown" with type Bool and the nodes are listening to this topic, when a message arrives the nodes shutdown themselves

Comment: hii thank you for your answer
I think i have just some mistake on the syntax.
But what i have figured out is using gnome ternimal to running some roslaunch

I will try it latter for your suggestion